# Win 7 Explorer backup and long paths

Tags: backup, windows-7

I use Explorer to do backups because Win 7's backup program asks me to take backups previously done and to put them back in the drive.  I am opposed to that idea since I believe backups should remain in storage.

With Explorer backups (burn and burn to disc) I have encountered the "destination path too long" error message and it shows the name of a folder "Debug" three times.  I have hundreds of folders named "Debug" thanks to Visual Studio.  At this moment I'm too angry at Microsoft to write a program to determine my 3 longest paths.  (Aside: This is all after coincidentally reading two articles about path junctions earlier this evening which already made me kind of unhappy.)

Please, is there an easy way to continue to make backups with Explorer?

Edit: I should add that renaming paths wrecks Visual Studio projects so I really need to isolate the small number of problem paths or find a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [robocopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx)?  This Microsoft command line tool is just FANTASTIC for user-initiated backups.

Comment: I tried it.  Robocopy cannot write to my D: drive which is a DVD drive.

Comment: Why..? Is there an error message?

Comment: Also, how much data (in terms of GB) are you trying to back up?